# PHP Date Formatting setting date in the future

Tags: php

Might be a really stupid question but I have a date

```
01NOV68
```

But when I parse it through php date function `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01NOV68'))` it is coming out like this `2068-11-01` is there a way in which i can stop this?

Comment: How do you expect PHP to "guess" that the date is 20th century rather than current century? You need to tell it which century you want!

Comment: This is the information i am getting out of a web services call for a date of birth so i assuming its 1968!

Comment: But PHP doesn't make the same assumptions that you do: PHP assumes current century, not a previous century; you need to tell PHP what century it should be